# Rails: dynamically naming instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops

Just wondering how to dynamically name (say, in a loop) a series of instance variables. Something like this:

```
<% @current_issue.articles.each_with_index do |a, i| %>
  <% i += 1 %>
  <%= f.collection_select("article#{i}", @articles_hash1, :first, :last) %>
  <% @articles1.each do |r| %>
    <%= link_to(image_tag(r.image.url(:large)), r.image.url(:large), :id => 'article'+i.to_s+'_thumb'+r.id.to_s) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Where instead of `@articles_hash1` it'd be `@articles_hash[i]`. I'm just not sure how to achieve that.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, do yourself a favour and build an array of the instance variables in question, i.e.:

```
@articles = (1..3).to_a.map { |i| Article.all_articles(i).reverse }
```

And then loop through that array, i.e.:

```
<% @articles.each_with_index do |a, i| %>
  <% i += 1 %>
  <%= f.collection_select("article#{i}", @articles[i-1], :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @current_issue.articles.each_with_index do |a, i| %>
  <%= f.collection_select("article#{i}", @articles_hash[i], :first, :last) %>
  <% @articles_hash[i].each do |r| %>
    <%= link_to(image_tag(r.image.url(:large)), r.image.url(:large), :id => 'article'+i.to_s+'_thumb'+r.id.to_s) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I didn't check for any syntax issues, but this should do.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It threw me this error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: My bad. @articles_hash must exist in the first place. How are you accessing it?

Comment: It does: I have the controller generating `@articles_hash1`, `@articles_hash2`, and `@articles_hash3`. It works fine (but obviously incorrectly) when I run the original code I posted.

Comment: Then is `@articles_hash1` a hash?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not accessing keys and values in a hash called `@articles_hash`, I'm accessing the three different hashes mentioned above. Sorry, I should have been clearer about that.